# Change of basis matrix logic question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logic

Is there any case for which there can be more than one change of basis matrix from one basis to another of the same dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any two basis for a vector space $V$, in order to write the change of basis matrix you represent the vectors in one basis as a linear combination of vectors in second basis. Since the representation must be unique, hence the matric must also be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The change-of-basis matrix is determined by the two bases.  Is that what you are asking?